# How to build params based on the length of the array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
function BuildParams(arr)
{

// arr is an Array
// how to build params based on the length of the array?
// for example when arr.Length is 3 then it should build the below:

var params = {                       
                        'items[0]' : arr[0],       
                        'items[1]' : arr[1],
                        'items[2]' : arr[2]
             },

return params;

}
```

Then I'd like to be able to send it to my ajax get:

```
var arr = ['Life', 'is', 'great'];

 $.get('/ControllerName/ActionName', BuildParams(arr))
                .done(function(data, status) {
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                });
```

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why aren't you using [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param)?

Comment: @zzzzBov Possibly because of this line in the doc: "If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray()" That indicates it won't handle an array of strings correctly.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, the object passed in should be an object: `$.param({items:arr})`. The objective is to set the array of values on the key of `items`.

Comment: $.param() doesn't help in the above situation because it doesn't generate {...}.

Comment: Oh, so you should be returning `{items:arr}` because behind the scenes jQuery will serialize the object passed using `$.param`.

Comment: Using $.param() would be fine, since then you'd be passing a string rather than an object, and jQuery won't serialize if it's already a string; output won't be *exactly* what they asked for, but it might still be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = {}
jQuery.each(['Life', 'is', 'great'], function(index, value){
    result['items[' + index + ']'] = value; 
});
```

[jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a
>   length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated
>   by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via
>   their named properties.

Comment: `{}` is simply an Object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array, adding each element in the array as a new property of a `params` object:

```
var params = {}; // start with an empty object
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    params["items[" + i + "]"] = arr[i];
}

return params; // return the populated params object
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `BuildParams(arr)` to:

```
{items: arr}
```

jQuery will correctly serialize objects into query-strings, including objects with items that are arrays.